# How to get values from HTML table to ASP.net C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I want to get values from HTML table to ASP.net C#
I am using those code:

```
  TableRowCollection rows = Table1.Rows;
  foreach(TableRow presentRow in rows) {
   presentKey = presentRow.Cells[2].Text;
  }
  Label1.Text = presentKey;
```

but, those code not working and show error:

> Error 14  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection to
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowCollection

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property `runat="server"` to the HTML tag you want to get access to it into C# code then on C# can you save it into variable and call it wherever you want.

Comment: Please provide me with the runat="server" tag you added and C# code.

Comment: <table id="myTable" class="table" runat="server">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <td>hh</td>
   <td>hh</td>
   <td>a</td>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>222</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>222</td>
   <td>112</td>
   <td>12</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>

Comment: Use `runat="server"` on the td tags and do not forget to give each td tag unique id then go to C# code and try to save td value in variable and test it in a compiler. e.g the first td tag will be `<td id="td1" runat="server"><p>paragraph</p></td>` go to C# code and add `String x = td1.toString(); Console.Write(x);` and see if it worked or not, if not try to add id and runat server properties to the paragraph tag same C# code but change the id.

Comment: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell  is appeared